# Wordpress: I have a custom change email form, how do I send confirmation email

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my functions.php to generate a form for users to change their account email from the front end. It works, but I'd like for it to send a the standard confirmation email Wordpress usually does when an email is changed, rather than instantly changing it. Is this simple, or difficult?

```html
function change_email_form() { 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_email = $user_info->user_email;
    ?>
    <form id="updateemail" action="#updateemail" method="post">
        <input id="new_email" type="text" name="new_email" title="new_email" placeholder="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" required>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Update Email</button>
    </form>
<?php }

function change_email(){
    if(isset($_POST['new_email'])){
        $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
        $new_email = sanitize_email($_POST['new_email']);
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_email = $user_info->user_email;
        $errors = array();
        $current_user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
        // Check for errors
        if ( $user_email == $new_email ) {
        $errors[] = 'Address unchanged';
        }
        if ( ! is_email( $new_email ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Address invalid';
        }
        if ( email_exists( $new_email ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Address unavailable';
        }
        if(empty($errors)){
            $args = array(
                'ID'         => $user_id,
                'user_email' => $new_email,
            );
            wp_update_user( $args );
            send_confirmation_on_profile_email();
            echo '<small class="notice">Address updated</small>';
        } else {
            // Echo Errors
            foreach($errors as $error){
                echo '<p>';
                echo '<small class="notice">';
                echo $error;
                echo '</small>';
            }
        }

    }
}

function email_form_shortcode(){
        change_email();
        change_email_form();
}
add_shortcode('changeemail_form', 'email_form_shortcode');
```

Comment: check this url https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/send_confirmation_on_profile_email/ here you find the solution

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have that function in my code, but it doesn't seem to work. I assume I need to pass it parameters, but I can't find anywhere what those are

Comment: check this url https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131488/wordpress-edit-user-profile-update-update-secondary-role may be this will be useful

Comment: Appreciate it, just not sure how that helps. Must be over my head.